# "project.copy" not working on MacOS High Sierra

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, macos-high-sierra

In my Android Studio project I have a small script, which creates from different Language Resources, `strings.xml` for Android and `.lproj` for iOS.

Until now, everything worked fine but then I upgraded to MacOS High Sierra. And now in my Android Studio project the gradle-Task which creates my String values fails cause it could not open the `values-da` Folder while moving the `string.xml` into the `res/` Folder.

The part where it fails is here:

```
project.fileTree(dir: scriptPath).visit {
    FileVisitDetails details ->
        if (details.file.name.startsWith("values-")) {
            println "copying " + details.file.absolutePath + " to " + resPath;
            //It fails here at .copy
            project.copy {
                from details.file.absolutePath
                into resPath + "/" + details.file.name
                // copy english resources to base values folder
                if (details.file.name.equals("values-en")) {
                    into resPath + "/values"
                }
            }

            details.file.deleteDir();
        }
}
```

My first guess was, that this could be related to the new Filesystem. Does anyone have similar Problems? I could verify that I probably is caused by High Sierra, cause my colleague has the same problem after updating to High Sierra.

Here the "What went wrong"-Message:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not read directory path '/Some/path/from/User/values-da'.
```

Here is the Stacktrace I got while running the task with `--stacktrace`:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not read directory    path '/Some/path/from/User/values-da'.
08:14:17.474 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.jdk7.Jdk7DirectoryWalker$1.postVisitDirectory(Jdk7DirectoryWalker.java:109)
08:14:17.474 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.jdk7.Jdk7DirectoryWalker$1.postVisitDirectory(Jdk7DirectoryWalker.java:58)
08:14:17.475 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.jdk7.Jdk7DirectoryWalker.walkDir(Jdk7DirectoryWalker.java:58)
08:14:17.475 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTree.walkDir(DirectoryFileTree.java:163)
08:14:17.475 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTree.visitFrom(DirectoryFileTree.java:147)
08:14:17.475 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTree.visit(DirectoryFileTree.java:132)
08:14:17.476 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.FileTreeAdapter.visit(FileTreeAdapter.java:110)
08:14:17.476 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileTree.visit(AbstractFileTree.java:123)
08:14:17.476 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileTree.visit(CompositeFileTree.java:64)
08:14:17.476 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileTree.visit(CompositeFileTree.java:58)
08:14:17.476 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.file.FileTree$visit.call(Unknown Source)
08:14:17.476 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at build_4z109ko3musne9trwmjez6vxh$_run_closure6.doCall(/Users/mtuchner/fotoplus-android/frontend-android/app/build.gradle:230)
08:14:17.477 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:70)
08:14:17.477 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configureTarget(ConfigureUtil.java:160)
08:14:17.477 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configureSelf(ConfigureUtil.java:136)
08:14:17.477 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.configure(AbstractTask.java:528)
08:14:17.477 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.create(DefaultTaskContainer.java:137)
08:14:17.478 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskContainer$create.call(Unknown Source)
08:14:17.478 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at build_4z109ko3musne9trwmjez6vxh.run(/Users/mtuchner/fotoplus-android/frontend-android/app/build.gradle:184)
08:14:17.478 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:90)
08:14:17.478 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   ... 62 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix my problem with a small change. 
After posting the stack trace I've seen, that the ".postVisitDirectory" Method of the JDK7FileProvider throws the error.

The documentation says, that this method is always called, after a visit in the FileTree. So I took the Delete Operation and out of the current visit and put it into a closure behind the `.visit{}` and it compiles again.

Here the code:

```
List<File> dirsToDelete = new ArrayList<File>()
// copy string resources from shared
project.fileTree(dir: scriptPath).visit {
    FileVisitDetails details ->
        if (details.file.name.startsWith("values-")) {
            println "copying " + details.file.absolutePath + " to " + resPath;
                project.copy {
                    from details.file.absolutePath
                    into resPath + "/" + details.file.name
                    // copy english resources to base values folder
                    if (details.file.name.equals("values-en")) {
                        into resPath + "/values"
                    }
                    dirsToDelete.add(details.file)
            }
        }
}.with {
    for(Iterator<File> i = dirsToDelete.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        File file = i.next();
        file.deleteDir();
    }
}
```